# Capture screen and output to video device

Tags: video, screencasting, sip

I'm using linphone, I I'd like to share my screen instead of my webcam.

Currently, it looks like linphone only supports reading video input from `/dev/video` using V4L, though I'll be happy to be corrected.

Is there any software that will allow me to capture my desktop and stream it to a faux video device, say `/dev/video1`?